# BigQuery - Cannot read and write in different locations: source: EU, destination: US

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I've created a basic instance in europe-west1-b.
I try to join data from 2 BigQuery tables and write the results back to BigQuery. 
I got this error :
java.io.IOException: Cannot read and write in different locations: source: EU, destination: US

The automatically created temporary storage bucket is located in the US while the Cloud Data Fusion instance and BigQuery tables are in the EU.

I fixed this issue by manually creating a bucket in the correct zone and specifying these in the sink/source.

Can this manual step be avoided by automatically picking the correct zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for notifying the issue. We have filed an enhancement bug https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-15372 to support picking up the right zone. Please watch that JIRA for the further updates.

Best Regards,

Sagar